# Read a line of text from an input stream in Java keeping the line-termination character(s)

Tags: java, line, inputstream

I have this code in Java:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(getInputStream());
BufferedReader ir = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;
while ((line = ir.readLine()) != null) {
 //do stuff with "line"
}
```

If the input stream contains the following: "hello\nhey\ryo\r\ngood-day", then line variable would be following on each iteration:

1. hello
2. hey
3. yo
4. good-day

I want to read one line at a time, but I want to keep the line-termination character(s):

1. hello\n
2. hey\r
3. yo\r\n
4. good-day

How can I do this? Is there a ready-made classes I can use?

--

**Update:**

Here's what I'm trying to do and why I need to keep the end-of-line character (and why the EOL character may be different).

I'm reading a POST request. They consists of pure text messages where the lines always end with \r\n (by the standard specification). However POST request may contain binary data, which may contain bytes that look like termination characters to Java Reader objects.

In my example, an image is being uploaded. The image data is sent on a single line. However, however the image's binary data contains bytes that the READER would interpret as "\n", "\r" or sometimes "\r\n" if those two bytes happens to be next to each other.

I have to read the POST request one line at a time because that's how it works. I suppose, I COULD read everything and then parse the whole thing. But that's not efficient, especially if a large file (say 1024 MiB) file is being uploaded.

Comment: If you can't find a better solution, you can implement your `readLine` using `BufferedReader.read()` in a `while` loop.

Comment: I was hoping that this very basic thing was already done, one would have thought that they could have made it so that the BufferedReader's readLine() method accepted a boolean - if true it would also include the line-seperator character(s) and if false it would behave like it does at the moment.

Comment: Is the particular end character important to keep? Because the first thing I thought was just appending a `\n` to the line

Comment: Most probably there is no such `readLine` function you are looking for built into Java. If you need it, either you implement it or find and use a third-party `.jar` file which contains it.

Comment: The premiss of the question is invalid. You shouldn't be using a Reader on binary data in the first place, and you shouldn't be reading binary data as lines either.

Comment: I'm not any more EJP. Although it's tricky since a POST request is sent as pure text + binary data (that is, some binary data could be read as pure text).

Comment: You don't have to read POST data line by line. You have to read the *headers* line by line, until a blank line, and then the binary data as binary. The only way do do both workably is via `DataInputStream', and yes a I know its `readKine()` method is deprecated, or to be a Servlet, which manages that for you. Somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to read a HTTP POST request, I strongly suggest using `BufferedInputStream.read()` (not `BufferedReader`!) directly (without `readLine`-like intermediate abstractions), paying attention to all details manually, including the handling of CR and LF according to the HTTP RFC.

Here is my answer to your more specific question (how to implement exactly that `readLine`). This might not be the fastest solution, but it's time complexity is optimal, and it works:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;   
public class LineReader {   
  private int i = -2;
  private BufferedReader br;
  public OriginalLineReader(BufferedReader br) { this.br = br; }
  public String readLine() throws IOException {
    if (i == -2) i = br.read();
    if (i < 0) return null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append((char)i);
    if (i != '\r' && i != '\n') {
      while (0 <= (i = br.read()) && i != '\r' && i != '\n') {
        sb.append((char)i);
      }
      if (i < 0) return sb.toString();
      sb.append((char)i);
    }
    if (i == '\r') {
      i = br.read();
      if (i != '\n') return sb.toString(); 
      sb.append((char)'\n');
    }
    i = -2;
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

You won't find such a `readLine` built into Java. It's likely that you will find similar, but not exactly matching `readLine`s in a third-party `.jar` file. My recommendation is just to use the one above, if you really need that feature.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of code I was hoping not having to write myself, thank you very much! Still think it should have been in Java by default though.

Comment: When those java APIs were designed platform-specific end of line encoding was even more wonky than it is now.  They are trying to insulate you from having to deal with \n vs \r vs \r\n vs God only knows what proprietary *Nixes were using in 1993, by providing readLine and writeLine and handling it internally.

Comment: Affe: I think there is a minor factual error in your reasoning. My general understanding is that all Unix systems always had `'\n'` (which is equal to `10`) as line terminator.

Comment: Thanks again pts, I originally used BufferedInputStream directly but thought of the readLine thing and got lazy. Didn't think of the problem with binary files then, hehe. I have gotten it to work now, and I'm sure your code will be useful for many more that comes here from searching the net.

Comment: Is there some reason not to use BufferedReader's readLine method?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29  Maybe this is new?

Comment: @fooledbyprimes: The original question asked for keeping the line termination characters, BufferedReader.readLine removes them. (See also the documentation you linked.)

Comment: shouldn't the "break" be a "continue"  instead?

Comment: @user2912902: No, it shouldn't. If you think otherwise, please provide an example input and the desired output for which it works with `continue;`, but not with `break;`.

Comment: @pts - This code is a good start, but it has multiple errors. First, the function never returns `null`, which it *should do* at EOF. (`BufferedReader.readLine` returns null at EOF).  Second, it drops the LF when a line ends in CRLF. The OP specifically indicated that if a line ends in CRLF, the output of readLine should preserve it, but your function loses the LF.  Here's a link to an online Java "fiddle" where you can see the output for your LineReader compared with the *corrected* version. http://goo.gl/noPO4l  (I'll upvote this when these issues are corrected)

Comment: @ricovox: Thanks for spotting these bugs, I've fixed them and updated my answer. Now the behavior is equivalent to your implementation.