# How to parse "SecciÃ³n" to "Sección"? (string accutes encoding issue)

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a string with this value "SecciÃ³n"

I need to parse it to UTF-8, so the string gets transformed to "Sección"

I tried with `line = new String(line.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");` but this does not work.

### Edit

I'm reading the string with this method:

```
public static String loadLine(InputStream is) {
        if (is == null)
            return null;

    final short TAM_LINE = 256;
    String line;
    char[] buffer = new char[TAM_LINE];
    short i;
    int ch;

    try {
        line = "";
        i = 0;
        do {
            ch = is.read();                
            if ((ch != '\n') && (ch != -1)) {
                buffer[i++] = (char)(ch & 0xFF);

                if (i >= TAM_LINE) {
                    line += new String(buffer, 0, i);
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
        } while ((ch != '\n') && (ch != -1));

        // Si no hemos llegado a leer ning�n caracter, devolvemos null
        if (ch == -1 && i == 0)
            return null;

        // A�adimos el �ltimo trozo de l�nea le�do
        line += new String(buffer, 0, i);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
        return null;
    }        
    return line;
}
```

Comment: `new String(line.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")` is just voodoo programming. I would recommend to first get a proper understanding of character encodings: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Where do you get the String from? Why is it created with the wrong encoding? At that stage, it is very often too late to fix it. You need to set the proper encoding before turning it into a String.

Comment: i added the method to the question

Comment: use an `InputStreamReader` to read in the data. Specify the proper encoding in its constructor. I think `BufferedReader` has a method to read one line at the time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445740/read-a-line-of-text-from-an-input-stream-in-java-keeping-the-line-termination-ch

Answer (score 0):

The character `ó` is encoded as `0xc3 0xb3` in UTF-8. It appears that whichever program read that UTF-8-encoded string in the first place read it assuming the wrong encoding, for example `windows-1252`, where `0xc3` encodes `Ã` and `0xb3` encodes `³`.

In your case, your edit shows that (as far as I can tell, I don't know Java), you're reading the input byte by byte, building the string one character at a time, one from each byte. This is not a good idea if the encoding `UTF-8` uses multiple bytes to encode certain characters such as `ó`.

You should read the input into a `bytes` array first, then [build a `String` using the correct encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.lang.String)):

```
line = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8")
```